# ag-grid-vue with ES5

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid

I am trying to use ag-grid-vue with ES5 (no webpack/babel etc). I get the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
at agGridVue.js:3

Does ag-grid-vue work with pure javascript or does it require a transpiler?

Comment: This is an option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334844/is-it-possible-to-use-ag-grid-with-vue-without-a-builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ag-grid-vue doesn't support pure JavaScript - it's written with ES6 in mind I'm afraid.