# Is it possible to use ag-grid with vue without a builder?

Tags: vuejs2, ag-grid

In particular, can the typescript source of the ag-grid-vue component be compiled then included in a regular html file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a way to do this without modifying the source.  Near the top of ag-grid-vue.umd.js, you can see that the module does this:

```
root["ag-grid-vue"] = factory(root["Vue"], root["agGrid"]);
```

Here, "root" is the window, and the result of the factory call is what you'll want.  But due to the dashes, you can't access it directly.  But you can use the dictionary syntax (or whatever it's called):

```
let agVueObj = window["ag-grid-vue"];
//The component is a field on this object:
let AgGridVue = agVueObj.AgGridVue;
//Then register it as a component in your Vue instance:
//components: { AgGridVue }
```

And you should be able to use `<ag-grid-vue>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

Download the ag-grid source code, go into the packages/ag-grid-vue directory and do `npm install` and `npm run build`. That will put compiled javascript modules in the dist directory that can be used without a build system.

I did have to modify the built javascript slightly to get the AgGridVue object into the global namespace, since I'm not using a module loader.

EDIT:
To get the `AgGridVue` into the global namespace, add `window.AgGridVue = AgGridVue;` to the end of the function that returns `AgGridVue` in `ag-grid-vue.umd.js`

Comment: Hi, I am trying to do the exact same thing. What did you change in `ag-grid-vue.umd.js`? Thanks!

Comment: At the end of the function which returns `AgGridVue`, I put the line `window.AgGridVue = AgGridVue;` to add the object into a namespace I could access from my code.

There's probably a better way to do it, but I don't really understand module loaders yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Not sure what the best solution to this would be, but at least it works :)

Comment: thank you for this, i spent the last 3 days scouring their documentation looking for an example of this. I was about to do exactly what you did here, but thanks for at least confirming that's the only option. Cheers