# Ag-Grid in Vue no npm install example?

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid

### I want to use **ag-grid-vue** without `npm` installing it.

code: https://codepen.io/riodw/pen/zYYOjdE

---

So I found this: [Is it possible to use ag-grid with vue without a builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334844/is-it-possible-to-use-ag-grid-with-vue-without-a-builder). Followed that guid, and was basically able to get something to render but it get's stuck on "Loading..."

1. I downloaded ag-grid (from here: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid)
2. Went into `cd ag-grid-master/packages/ag-grid-vue`
3. npm installed `npm install`
4. Then built `npm run build`

This generated the "**ag-grid-vue.umd.js**" file.
Modified that file to put **AgGridVue** on the window where AgGridVue is returned:

```
window.AgGridVue = AgGridVue;
return AgGridVue;
```

Then include that file with the ag-grid-community file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ag-grid/21.2.1/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
<script src="/global/js/ag-grid/ag-grid-vue.umd.js"></script>
```

**And ag-grid renders!**
Problem is it get's stuck on loading and I don't know if there is a solution.
Are there any possibilities to help here?
Any help would be great. If not I'll have to use something else as installing is not an option for me unfortunately.

### Image of render:

[image]

Debug mode codepen:
https://cdpn.io/riodw/debug/zYYOjdE/LDkmdEDdQpzA

Comment: Have you ever find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 4):

Everything you do is correct except one tiny thing.

I've found the solution, when I've used vue.js (not minified version), then Vue itself has thrown a warning;

[image]

Indicating that, in the "**ag-grid-vue**" tag, you should not use **:rowData** as below;

```
<ag-grid-vue :rowData="rowData" :columnDefs="columnDefs"/>
```

this usage is wrong as stated in the console warning from Vue.

You should use **kebab-case instead of camel-case** as below;

```
<ag-grid-vue :row-data="rowData" :column-defs="columnDefs"/>
```

This actually works as expected.

I beleive, camel-case works in an environment with the presence of module-loader.