# Ag-Grid with VueJS (vanillajs)

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I'm trying to implement Ag-Grid with VueJS but in a vanillajs version(without any package or module manager).

I've tried to use umd version of ag-grid (https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-vue@22.1.1/dist/ag-grid-vue.umd.js) as in below example.

https://jsfiddle.net/p429h0sL/

But below error was thrown;

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <ag-grid-vue> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

I've also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334844/is-it-possible-to-use-ag-grid-with-vue-without-a-builder) but no luck with that either.

Can you tell me how to proceed ?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the solution.

First thing I needed to do, add line as suggested in [this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334844/is-it-possible-to-use-ag-grid-with-vue-without-a-builder)

After adding this line in ag-grid-vue.umd.js;

```
window.AgGridVue = AgGridVue;
```

before this line;

```
     return AgGridVue;
}(external_commonjs_vue_commonjs2_vue_root_Vue_default.a));
```

This way, I've wired AgGridVue variable into window object, which in result it can be used globally in js environment.

Second thing, I've called proper js files

```
<script src="ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
<script src="ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script> <!-- This line is optional, if you want to use enterprise features -->
<script src="vue.js"></script>
<script src="ag-grid-vue.umd.js"></script> <!-- This is the manipulated file -->
```

And after that I've instantiated Vue and ag-grid

```
<div id="vue" style="width:100%;height:600px">

    <ag-grid-vue style="width:100%;height:600px" class="ag-theme-bootstrap" :column-defs="columnDefs"
        :row-data="rowData" ></ag-grid-vue>

</div>

 <script>

    let vueData = {
        gridApi: null,
        rowData: [{test:1}],
        columnDefs: [{field:"test",headerName:"test"}]
    };

    window.onload = function () {



        Vue.component("ag-grid-vue", AgGridVue);

        let vue = new Vue({
            el: "#vue",
            data: vueData,
        })

    }
</script>
```

Important note : You should not use **camelCase** prop names within **ag-grid-vue** tag ([as I explained in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58243261/ag-grid-in-vue-no-npm-install-example)). Instead you must use **kebap-case** declaration..

This way everything works fine.

Comment: Just adding the line up there was the solution I've been looking for for a while. Excellent!

Comment: Thank you, kind human :)