# Ag-Grid with VueJS 2 giving TypeError: Class constructor BaseComponentWrapper cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid

I'm currently using ag-grid with Vue 2 without npm / builder
downloaded from https://unpkg.com/browse/ag-grid-community@31.0.1/ and https://unpkg.com/browse/ag-grid-vue@31.0.1/

base.html

```
<script src="../static/javascript/ag-grid-community.js"></script>
<script src="../static/javascript/ag-grid-vue.umd.js"></script>
<script src="../static/components/subpage.js"></script>
```

subpage.js

```
 Vue.component("ag-grid-vue", AgGridVue);

...
<ag-grid-vue style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"
    class="ag-theme-quartz-dark"
    :columnDefs="dummyColumns"
    :rowData="dummyData">
</ag-grid-vue>
...
```

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59565934/ag-grid-with-vuejs-vanillajs), I managed to start the vue page but getting the following error, any idea how to resolve? Thanks.

```
TypeError: Class constructor BaseComponentWrapper cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

I tried with different versions of ag-grid-community.js, like .amd / .cjs / .esm but no luck